# Why does apt-get upgrade give ELF file warning?

Tags: apt, upgrade

Executing sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade:

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get upgrade

gives the following message, which I think is a warning:

> /sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/libf2c.so is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.

Where is the origin of that and how can I fix it? I am running Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits! Thank you in advance.

PD This question is similar to that asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333513/wrong-magic-bytes-at-the-start-in-lib) but it has no solution yet :/

EDIT: I just found [a similar question that was indeed answered](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316518/errors-during-apt-get-upgrade):
So is this a bug and I can do nothing??!

Answer (score 2):

You might have a corrupted file, so try removing and reinstalling the libf2c2 and libf2c2-dev packages:

```
sudo apt-get purge libf2c2-dev
sudo apt-get purge libf2c2
sudo apt-get install libf2c2
sudo apt-get install libf2c2-dev
```

The question you refer to has another problem, their file is a python script, so of course it is not an ELF file.

---

Fixed the package names.

Comment: I just tried to follow your instructions, but bash didn't find the package: <br/>


`$ sudo apt-get purge libf2c  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
E: Unable to locate package libf2c`  


Nevertheless, it finds the packages libf2c2 and libf2c2-dev. What to do then?

Thank you